# Get major and minor version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Running following query:

```
SELECT 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS version,
    SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion') AS major, 
    SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMinorVersion') AS minor;
```

produces the following results:

```
version      major   minor
------------ ------- -------
10.0.2531.0  NULL    NULL
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ProductMajorVersion` and `ProductMinorVersion` properties are only available in SQL Server 2012 and above (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql). Your product version indicates that this is SQL Server 2008 SP1, which does not support the two other properties.

Answer (score 2):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)</sub>*

One can use `PARSENAME` to extract the major and minor versions from `ProductVersion` pre-SQL Server 2012:

```
PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS varchar(20)), 4) AS major,
PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS varchar(20)), 3) AS minor
```

The `PARSENAME` method should work regardless of version, but you could `COALESCE` to use the major/minor property when available:

```
SELECT 
    SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS version,
    COALESCE
    (
        SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMajorVersion'), 
        PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS varchar(20)), 4)
    ) AS major, 
    COALESCE
    (
        SERVERPROPERTY('ProductMinorVersion'), 
        PARSENAME(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS varchar(20)), 3)
    ) AS minor;
```